# Trying to select 3rd element of $(this) JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of dates and times, where i want the user to hover over a time slot, and get jquery to highlight not only that hovered td but the second td in the column after that current highlight...
**Snippet of table**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Thursday 5</th>
        <th>Friday 6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td time="900" date="2015-02-05" class="free"> 900 </td>
        <td time="900" date="2015-02-06" class="free"> 900 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td time="930" date="2015-02-05" class="free">930</td>
        <td time="930" date="2015-02-06" class="free"> 930 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td time="1000" date="2015-02-05" class="free"> 1000 </td>
        <td time="1000" date="2015-02-06" class="free"> 1000 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If someone hovers over 900 on 2015-02-06 it will also highlight 1000 on 2015-02-06.

This is my javascript which highlights the whole day, i've been trying to use :eq(2) and :nth-of-type(2) but to no avail. Also using $this.eq(2) but also no luck.

**Current Javascript**

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
    if( $(this).val() === 'Two Appointments'){
        $('td.free').hover(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("oneAppt");
        var dateAttr = $(this).attr("date");
        $("[date="+dateAttr+"]").addClass("twoAppt");
        }, function(){
            var dateAttr = $(this).attr("date");
            $("td [date="+dateAttr+"]").removeClass("twoAppt");
        });
    } else {
        $('td.free').hover(function(){
        var dateAttr = $(this).attr("date");
        $("*[date="+dateAttr+"]").removeClass("twoAppt");
        $( this ).addClass( "oneAppt" );
        }, function(){
            $(this).removeClass("oneAppt");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: You're adding and re-adding those "hover" functions on each click. They don't go away automatically.

Comment: Also, `this` refers to an specific element, not a set of elements.

Comment: Right - as @JCOC611 says, there will **never** be a "3rd element" of `$(this)` in an event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data` attributes as follows:

```js
$(function() {
  $('tr:has(.free):first td').on('mouseenter',function() {
    var that = $(this);
    $(this).parent().next().next().find('td').filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('date') == that.data('date');
    })
    .addClass('highlight');
    that.addClass('highlight');
  })
  .on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight
{
  background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Thursday 5</th>
        <th>Friday 6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-time="900" data-date="2015-02-05" class="free"> 900 </td>
        <td data-time="900" data-date="2015-02-06" class="free"> 900 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-time="930" data-date="2015-02-05" class="free">930</td>
        <td data-time="930" data-date="2015-02-06" class="free"> 930 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td data-time="1000" data-date="2015-02-05" class="free"> 1000 </td>
        <td data-time="1000" data-date="2015-02-06" class="free"> 1000 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $('.free').on('mouseover', function() {
        var idx = $(this).index();
        $(this).addClass('hl');
        $(this).parent().next().next().find('td').eq(idx).addClass('hl');
    });
    $('.free').on('mouseout', function() {
        $('.free').removeClass('hl');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/se51kk2w/

Answer (score 0):

**

```js
$(function() {
    $('.free').on('mouseover', function() {
        var idx = $(this).index();
        $(this).addClass('hl');
        $(this).parent().next().find('td').eq(idx).addClass('hl');
    });
    $('.free').on('mouseout', function() {
        $('.free').removeClass('hl');
    });
});
```

```css
.hl {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Thursday 5</th>
        <th>Friday 6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td time="900" date="2015-02-05" class="free"> 900 </td>
        <td time="900" date="2015-02-06" class="free"> 900 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td time="930" date="2015-02-05" class="free">930</td>
        <td time="930" date="2015-02-06" class="free"> 930 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td time="1000" date="2015-02-05" class="free"> 1000 </td>
        <td time="1000" date="2015-02-06" class="free"> 1000 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```